# How to detect if a video file is supported by the HTML5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a File object in JavaScript of a file in the user's machine and I want link to it in a `video` tag and play it. The problem is that I need to detect first if the browser supports the codec of the file I have, how do I do that? I know I can detect what codecs the browser supports with the `canPlayType()` function, but how can I detect the codec of the file I have?

Comment: You could use the extension of the file in question?

Comment: @Ian Devlin Yes I could, but for example if the extension is MP4, how could I know if the codec is H.264 or MPEG-4?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, it can either play MP4 files or it can't, you won't really be able to dig any deeper than that.

Comment: @Ian Devlin Not really, MP4 is only the container, while the codec is what really matters.

Comment: Yeah I know that, have answered in detail below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into it more, and canPlayType() can also contain the codec, so you can try:

```
canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"');
```

and

```
canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"');
```

separately for example

Answer (score 0):

*"I have a File object in JavaScript of a file in the user's machine... I know I can detect what codecs the browser supports with the `canPlayType()` function, but how can I detect the codec of the file I have?"*

**(1) If codec is known...** Use `canPlayType` to check codec compatibility.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideoElementID");

//# for AVC1 codecs like avc1.42E01E
if( vid.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1"') )
{ alert("can play AVC1 / H.264 "); }
```

**(2) If codec is unknown...** Check file bytes for codec type (then do **step (1)** to confirm playability)

This means getting **a chunk of the file's bytes** (for example getting the first 64kb or last 64kb, depends if MP4 header is at front or back of file).

Read the data into an **Array** and then search that Array for the `stsd` section, which is where MP4 keeps the Sequence Parameter Set (SPS) of the H264 data, from that section you can get extract the codec info.

a) Find `stsd` position.
b) From that position, skip `+16` bytes to find either `avc1` or `hev1`.
c) From the `+16` pos, skip forward from here `+91` to get the SPS (3 bytes).

Here is an example using a selected (local) file which is read into an Array via FileReader API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- button Choose MP4 Video -->
<div style="z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 10px; " >
<text> <b> Choose a Video (.MP4) file...</b> <br> 
<input type="file" id="choose_video" accept=".mp4" />
</div>

<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="480" controls  style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 10px; " >
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>

<script>

var temp_int = 0; var temp_str = ""; var temp_arr = [];

var reader; var path;
var fileBytes;  //# is updated to: uint8Array []
var file; //# a File object (using Reader) 

//# codec name (is String object)
var str_codec = "-1";

var myvid = document.getElementById( 'myVideo' );

addEventListener("load", on_page_Ready );

function on_page_Ready()
{
    //# listener for selecting MP4 file
    document.getElementById('choose_video').addEventListener('change', onSelectFile, false);
}

function onSelectFile(evt) 
{
    file = evt.target.files[0]; //# FileList object
    path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
    
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        
    reader.onload = function(evt)
    {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
        {
            fileBytes = new Uint8Array( evt.target.result );
            
            //# extract codec info
            get_MP4_Codec( fileBytes ); 
            
            //# load video data and play ...
            myvid.setAttribute("src", path);
            myvid.load();
            
            myvid.play();
        }
    }
}

function get_MP4_Codec (inBA)
{
    let idx = 0; //# index (position) in bytes
    
    while(true)
    {
        //# auto stop if "stsd" not found after 32 kilobytes
        if ( (idx > 32000) || (idx >= inBA.length-1) ) { break; }
        
        //# look for starting "s" (is byte value 0x73)
        if( inBA[ idx ] == 0x73 ) //# find "s"
        {
            //# check if next following 3 bytes are the required values
            if( (inBA[ idx+1 ] == 0x74) &&  //# find "t"
                (inBA[ idx+2 ] == 0x73) &&  //# find "s"
                (inBA[ idx+3 ] == 0x64)     //# find "d"
            )
            {
                //# when found... 
                
                //# note the "stsd" position
                temp_int = idx; 
                
                //# skip forward by 16 bytes to get codec type
                //# codec type can be "avc1" or "hev1" or "hvc1"
                
                idx += 16;
                str_codec =  String.fromCharCode( inBA[ idx+0 ] );
                str_codec += String.fromCharCode( inBA[ idx+1 ] );
                str_codec += String.fromCharCode( inBA[ idx+2 ] );
                str_codec += String.fromCharCode( inBA[ idx+3 ] );
                
                //# need that dot "." also
                str_codec += ".";
                
                //# skip forward by 91 bytes to get codec SPS details
                //# example"avc1.64001f" the SPS is "64001F"
                idx += 91;
                
                temp_str = (inBA[idx].toString(16)).toUpperCase();
                str_codec += temp_str.length === 2 ? temp_str : '0' + temp_str;
                
                idx += 1;
                temp_str = (inBA[idx].toString(16)).toUpperCase();
                str_codec += temp_str.length === 2 ? temp_str : '0' + temp_str;
                
                idx += 1;
                temp_str = (inBA[idx].toString(16)).toUpperCase();
                str_codec += temp_str.length === 2 ? temp_str : '0' + temp_str;
                
                break;
                
            }
            
        }
        
        idx++;
    }
    
    alert("found STSD @ byte pos : " + temp_int +"\n"+ "codec type : " + str_codec );

}

</script>

</html>
```